# Retrieving data between tables (Pivot Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, category and activity where than I created a pivot table activity_categories which saves the activity_id and category_id.

I have created my models which works in retrieving data but now I want to get all activities from activity table which belongs to a particular category in category table.

I tried with loop but couldn't make it work.
My code is as below:

//Activity model

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category','activity_categories');
}
```

//controller

```
$activities = Activity::all();

    foreach ($activities as $activity){
        $fun = Activity::all()->where($activity->category->first()->name, 'fun');
        dd($fun);
    }
    return view('layout.home', compact('activities'));
```

If i try to dd it returns null although I have numerous data in this category. 
Note, an activity may belong to many categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the reverse relationship in the `Category` model:

```
public function activity()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Activity', 'activity_categories');
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
$category = Category::find($id);
$activities = $category->activity;
```

Comment: Than how am I suppose to display activity data which are found in activity table based on the category?

Comment: I included the relationship but the id is part of what? I do not have anything related to activity saved in category table. Their only connection is the pivot table activity_categories

Comment: You wrote that you want to get all activities that belong to a particular category. Of course, you can also use `$categories = Category::all();`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, but is there any way to only display once. ex. if one activity is displayed in the first category than do not display it in the second one.

Comment: Does a list of unique activities help you? `$uniqueActivities = $categories->pluck('activity')->collapse()->unique('id');`

Comment: not really, but it's ok i got the main point. Thank you very much.

Comment: $fun_category = Category::find(4);
$fun_activities = $fun_category->activity;
Like this works but I want to display based on the latest activity

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the latest activity"? Do you want to order the activities?

Comment: yes, like the descending order and also can I do something like this:
        $fun_activities  = $fun_category->activity('start_date_time', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+2 hour')))->get();

Comment: You can use the relationship like a normal query: `$fun_category->activity()->where('start_date_time', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('+2 hour')))->orderyByDesc('start_date_time')->get()`.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas, works with the latest(). Thank you very much.